# How to enable DEBUG level logging with Jetty from UI

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to set the logging level to DEBUG in a Jetty instance. It is working when we add
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
-Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=DEBUG  Under property file and pass it to the JVM.
My use case is I was trying to set logging level from UI so that without restarting the server we can switch logging level.
for example, DEBUG to WARN

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Jetty 9 and StdErrLog with JMX**

Using Jetty 9, enable JMX on the server, and use a JMX client to set the StdErrLog debug attributes.

Look for MBean Name `org.eclipse.jetty.util.log:type=stderrlog,id=0`
The attribute is called `debugEnabled` (a boolean).

**Option 2: Jetty 10+ and jetty-slf4j-impl with JMX**

If using Jetty 10+, enable JMX on the server, and use a JMX client to set the level on your logger of choice.

Eg: if you are using the `jetty-slf4j-impl` (the spiritual successor of `StdErrLog`) ...
Look for MBean Name `org.eclipse.jetty.logging:type=jettyloggerfactory,id=0`
All of the named loggers are listed as attributes.
The operations let you `getLoggerLevel` and `setLoggerLevel` using normal JMX operation techniques.

**Option 3: Different Logging Framework**

Alternatively, you can use a more robust logger, like logback, or log4j2, or even java.util.logging and have even more options of runtime control over the logging.

Some offer runtime control over JMX.

Some offer the ability to reload the configuration if the configuration file changes.

Check your logger to know what it can do.

**Option 4: Write your own logger level change API**

You can easily write your own tooling to change the logger level based on some kind of event that your own application is in control over.

You can even make this a Handler on Jetty that only responds to specific named ServerConnectors that only list on localhost.

You just need to fetch the named `Logger` and then set the level. (the exact API and technique depends on your chosen logger implementation)